# Does a complement phrase always follow a be verb?

Tags: copular-verbs, complements, predicative-complements

### Summary question

- Is there a formal name for the entire portion of a sentence that is connected to the copula?"
- Is it "complement"?

### Background

Be verb can be followed by various things: a noun (He is blue.), a be verb can be followed by a verb (Who is running?), etc.  But is what follows the be verb always a "complement", even if it is more than one word (e.g., is the emboldened all part of the complement in the following sentence: "They are **happily distance running in the beautiful park**.")?

Perhaps I should be asking: 'could a predicate phrase--the part of a sentence that is a predicate--also be called a complement phrase--the part of a sentence that is a complement'?  I'm wondering because a "complement phrase" would seem to be more specific to be verbs?

Additionally, how about this list:

### Possible followings

**to be/to have been +**:

- nothing.
- gerund(s) (-ing).
- past-participle(s) (-ed).
- either of the above two + object(s).
- noun(s)/noun phrase(s).
- adjective.
- 0-valency prepositions.
- combinations of the above two.
- any of the above with adverbs (*except only adverbs) and/or prepositions.

**to be/to have been (not followed by) !+**:

- simple past verb(s).
- verb root(s).
- adverb(s) (*unless preceded by commas).
- one-or-more-valency prepositions.
- conjunctions.
- interjections (*except onomatopoeia).

### Purposes

Software, education.

Comment: I am an ELU user *(noun)* and I'm trying *(verb)* to be helpful *(adjective)*, but I can't see what you're getting at. And I'm not sure the [*complement clause*](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/glossaryoflinguisticterms/WhatIsAComplementClause.htm) categorisation system is meaningfully compatible with that of [*predicate phrases*](http://www.gabormelli.com/RKB/Predicate_Phrase). Which may both have various different definitions, so perhaps you could *define **your** terms*.

Comment: What is a complement phrase? Anyway, [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28linguistics%29) goes into detail about what I think you're talking about

Comment: Can I paraphrase your question as: if I say *"I am …"*, is the part after the *"am"* always called a complement?

Comment: What I'm looking at is, for example, "I am..."  And it is followed by: adjective, auxiliary, p.t. verb, gerund, article + noun, preposition + place/activity, or adverb + any of these....  So, I was hoping for a hyponym, essentially.

Comment: For example, maybe 'predicative expression'?

Comment: In sentences like *"I am coming tomorrow"* or *"I am going fishing"*, *"coming"* and *"going"* are part of the verb, and not part of a complement.

Comment: @Peter: This type of terminology isn't my strong point, but I suspect that in the ["Cartesian"](http://unenlightenedenglish.com/2009/07/i-think-therefore-i-am-confused-what-does-this-phrase-mean) sentence **I am**, the verb *to be* is actually the *predicate*.

Comment: @ Wolfpack'08: Since you still haven't edited the question text to provide ***your*** definitions for the terms you're using, I'm closevoting as "Unclear What You're Asking".

Comment: @PeterShor But the predicate participates with the verb, so they're generally grouped together (i.e., 'to be going fishing not' 'to fishing').

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question requests definitions, so you may as well ask me to answer my own question.  It's kind of silly because I wouldn't be asking if I knew the answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Still, of course, I followed your recommendations to the best of my ability (see update).

Comment: @ Wolfpack'08: You misunderstand me. A few seconds googling suggests different people have different definitions for "predicate phrase" and "complement phrase". It seems the second is equivalent to [complement clause](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/glossaryoflinguisticterms/WhatIsAComplementClause.htm), where *that* site says *A complement clause is a notional sentence or predication that is an argument of a predicate. The term complement clause is extended **by some analysts** to include clauses selected by nouns or adjectives.* I'm asking what definitions *you* use for your terminology.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My confusion here is that a "clause" must have a subject and a verb, right?  So, it would not include nouns, noun phrases, verb phrases without subjects, or adjectives--not to mention many combinations of these and adverb-containing versions of all of these.  So, I intentionally avoided use of the word 'clause' in the initial question.  What I'm trying to find is the ~proper~ term for the portion of the sentence which directly 'follows' and 'participates with' the be verb.

Comment: @ Wolfpack'08: There are so many different ways of using the verb ***to be*** that I think it's rather meaningless to ask for a "proper" term that applies to all of them. By most definitions, all three forms of ***to be*** in the first sentence of my first comment are actually *part of* the predicate [phrase] following the ***subject*** (***I*** in all cases). Essentially, a *sentence* (or *clause* within a sentence) consists of a *subject* and a *predicate* - so the verb is part of the predicate, since it's not part of the subject.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not looking for a term for uses, but rather a term for items that follow and are connected to the be verb.  Perhaps there is none, but I think it's useful in the same way other items of this kind are useful: it helps people to begin to form patterns in their mind to recognize trends more naturally.  There's really only a short, limited set of patterns that directly follow and connect to the be verb.

Comment: Perhaps the term ***complement*** is what you are looking for. :)

Comment: Be aware that "complement" is a kind of syntactic function. This is different from a kind of category (e.g. NP, AdjP, AdvP, DeterminativePhrase, etc.) The term "complement" is a rather general, or broad, term which basically covers some more specific terms--that is, complements of a clause can be, for example: subject, object, predicative complement. (For instance, an "object" is a special type of complement.) These are types of functions found within a clause structure. Those functions can be realized by stuff from categories: such as NP, AdjP, AdvP, etc.

Comment: @F.E. That's interesting.  I think I need to do more reading about complements to fully understand what you mean, seeing specific examples of complements in various locations.

Comment: The verb BE has various different types of uses, in various different types of **clauses**. For instance, there are the following: i *"She **was** a lawyer"* (copular BE); ii *"She **was** sleeping peacefully"* (progressive BE); iii *"They **were** seen by the security guard"* (passive BE); iv *"You **are** not to tell anyone"* (quasi-modal BE); v *"She has **been** to Paris twice already"* (motional BE); vi *"Why don't you **be** more tolerant?"* (lexical BE). Examples borrowed from the 2002 CGEL, page 113.

Comment: @F.E.: I think both comments are incisive here. Following OP's edit maybe "Unclear" isn't quite appropriate (I now lean towards "Too Broad"). Perhaps the heart of the problem here is that OP is conjoining *functional/structural* classification systems. Or perhaps it's just that all such systems are created in order to cover as many *general* aspects of language (not necessarily just *English*) as possible - but the most common English verbs *(be, have)* don't fit very neatly into those more "general-purpose" categorisations. I dunno - maybe this is a matter to explore on meta.

Comment: @F.E. - That's a really useful list.  The only thing I'm concerned about now is getting into more detail and seeing tense changes work against that list.